# Creating a computational table to show the number of overlapping genes between all possible pairs of combinations in eight gene lists

Tags: r, rstudio

I am relatively new to **R** programming and I am attempting to create a table to show whether any of the genes between 8 gene lists overlap. Below I have included the coding I currently have:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/R_Project/Gene_overlap")
getwd()
files <- list.files(pattern="*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
files

data.list <- lapply(files, function(fil) {
  scan(file=fil, what=character())
})

names(data.list) <- basename(files) %>% stringr::str_remove("\\.txt$")

str(data.list)
# List of 8
# $ GSE108363_BCGdown_D: chr [1:350] "IL1B" "IL6" "IL1A" "CCL20" ...
# $ GSE108363_BCGdown_V: chr [1:267] "IL6" "CCL20" "IL1A" "CXCL5" ...
# $ GSE108363_BCGup_D  : chr [1:250] "FABP4" "CMTM2" "FUCA1" "CD36" ...
# $ GSE108363_BCGup_V  : chr [1:429] "FCN1" "FCGR3B" "MNDA" "CPVL" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBdown_D: chr [1:86] "CCL20" "IL1B" "IL1A" "IL6" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBdown_V: chr [1:244] "IL1B" "IL1A" "CCL20" "IL6" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBup_D  : chr [1:128] "FUCA1" "FGL2" "TGFBI" "CPVL" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBup_V  : chr [1:286] "FABP4" "RNASE1" "MNDA" "CPVL" ...

intersect(data.list$GSE108363_BCGdown_D, data.list$GSE108363_BCGdown_V) %>% length

sapply(data.list, length)

set.seed(11)
BCG_validation_Up <- sample(letters[1:429], )
BCG_discovery_Up <- sample(letters[1:250], )
MTB_validation_Up <- sample(letters[1:286], )
MTB_discovery_Up <- sample(letters[1:128], )
BCG_validation_Down <- sample(letters[1:267], )
BCG_discovery_Down  <- sample(letters[1:350], )
MTB_validation_Down <- sample(letters[1:244], )
MTB_discovery_Down <- sample(letters[1:86], )

cross_table <- matrix(, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
rownames(cross_table) <- c("BCG_validation_Up", "BCG_discovery_Up", "MTB_validation_Up", "MTB_discovery_Up")
colnames(cross_table) <- c("BCG_validation_Down", "BCG_discovery_Down", "MTB_validation_Up", "MTB_discovery_Up")

for (i in 1:4){
  for(j in 1:4){
    cross_table[i,j] <- length(intersect(get(paste0("",i,"_Up")),(get(paste0("",j,"_Down")))))
  }
} 

cross_table
```

How can I alter this to successfully find the overlaps?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested...

```
library(dplyr) # for pipes the %>% symbol
tgenes <- data.list %>% unlist %>% table
names(tgenes[tgenes==8])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I tried it and got the following: Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

> tgenes <- data.list %>% unlist %>% table
> names(tgenes[tgenes==8])
character(0)

Comment: It looks like there are no genes that are in all 8 vectors - try with `tgenes[tgenes > 1] %>% sort(decreasing=TRUE)` to confirm that in general the approach works

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
sapply(data.list, function(x) sapply(data.list, function(y) sum(x %in% y)))
```

If you want to find genes that are common to all lists then use:

```
Reduce(intersect, data.list)
```

Or if you want to find genes common to any other subset of lists then use:

```
index_of_interest = c(2, 5, 7)

Reduce(intersect, data.list[index_of_interest])
```

I've just realised you may not want to compare all items in the list against all others. In this case the first sapply() is for the columns and the second sapply() is for the rows.

```
sapply(elements_for_columns, function(x) sapply(elements_for_rows, function(y) sum(x %in% y)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. The code to look at the possible overlap between all the different gene sets is as follows:

```
# seq_along(gene.lists) # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
for (i in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
  g1 <- gene.lists[[i]]
  for (j in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
    g2 <- gene.lists[[j]]
    a <- intersect(g1, g2)
    b <- length(a)
    mx.overlap.count[j,i] <- b
  }
}

mx.overlap.count
View(mx.overlap.count)
```